# What exactly is the rockoon niche? When are they preferable to normal rockets and vice versa? When ought rockoons to be used?

Tags: rockoon

This seems like a very basic question, but I am unable to find a clear answer. In what kind of space mission would using any kind of [rockoon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rockoon) design be a sensible decision and in what instances would a rockoon be simply a waste of time and resources? Is it a matter of small payloads vs. large payloads, a difference in where you are going, in what you are trying to collect? What kind of niche does the rockoon fall into? When ought they to be used?

Comment: If rockoons had advantages they'd be in use, the fact they aren't means they don't have a niche.

Comment: @GdD worse than that, they were used early on as a way to reach higher altitudes with sounding rockets, but they fell out of use as rocket performance improved. (Though there's some groups still trying to use them.) Even a mediocre first stage will blow past balloon altitude while pushing a heavier upper stage. Some things aren't done just because nobody's done them yet, but rockoons were abandoned because better things came along.

Comment: One of the big limitations is the availability of helium, unless you want to use hydrogen. We all know what a great idea *that* is.

Comment: @GdD: Hydrogen is fine for an unmanned vehicle.  (In fact, it's probably safe enough even for a manned vehicle, with the proper precautions; you see cars and piston planes running around all the time fuelled by gasoline, and that ignites at a lower temperature than hydrogen does.)

Comment: so, from the responses i have gotten it seems like the consensus is:
1) rockoons are not used nowadays
2) when they are, its not to escape gravity or enter orbit, merely to reach x km up more cheaply

Comment: I don't think launch from surface of Venus would be possible without a rockoon.

Comment: Common mistake: You don't get to space by travelling upwards. You get there by going very fast horizontally.

Answer (score 18):

Rockoons were in use during the very early part of the space rocketry era. The sounding rockets being used to survey the upper part of the atmosphere were small and inefficent, but cheap. Sounding rockets generally go nearly straight up, and don't need to reach high horizontal velocities, the way ICBMs and orbital launchers do. A balloon launch setup of practical size can give a fair amount of advantage to a sounding rocket with a payload on the order of 10 kg, but would have to be inconveniently large to do anything useful for an ICBM with a 1000 kg payload that needs to reach near-orbital speeds.

Once you have more efficient solid rocket motors available, it's simpler and cheaper to just scale up the rocket slightly and omit the balloon. The rockoon niche, basically, was the 1950s, though [a few small aerospace companies are still toying with the idea today](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rockoon#Recent_usage).

Comment: +1 for what I think is the main point: for getting to space (which is explicitly mentioned in the question), going fast is a much bigger problem than gaining altitude, and balloons only help with the latter.

Comment: @llama: OP only mentioned getting to space, not getting into an orbit. For getting to space you merely have to get above 100km. The record for high altitude balloons can get you halfway there.

Comment: Ok but so that is still evading the question a bit, now in the modern day when we do have efficient solid fuel rockets, why are people still playing around with rockoons, what benefit is seen by them in this instance?

Comment: @Michael Yes, but in general just getting into space isn’t very useful. What’s useful is getting into orbit.

Comment: @stoby there is no real benefit for orbital rocketry.  I didn't look through all the groups working on rockoons, but most seem primarily interested in airships, with small sat launches as an afterthought. It's much like airplane based sat launches, a couple companies toying around with an idea that has next to no hope of succeeding commercially -- the micro/nano - small sat market is already saturated with much better options already (or soon to be) in operation.

Answer (score 8):

Looking back on the late 1990s' [X Prize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansari_X_Prize), one of the contestants was the [da Vinci Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Da_Vinci_Project). Their concept involved a balloon-launched rocket. The long-term vision behind the X Prize was to bring space travel to the general public, which would require a substantial reduction in cost. The rockoon would seem to be a cheaper pathway to space, which is presumably the rationale behind the da Vinci Project concept. The X Prize was won by a rocket-powered craft launched at altitude from a jet-powered aircraft which became the foundation of the Virgin Galactic space tourism venture (still a work-in-progress); the da Vinci effort, on the other hand, seems to be drifting into obscurity. The rockoon is one of those ideas which, on the surface, seems like a better idea than it turns out to be in practice.

Answer (score 7):

The concept of the 'rockoon' was first thought of for non-orbital sounding rocket usage.  It was first used to launch sounding rockets off a ship in 1952.

Claimed advantages for this application are:

- Limited ground infrastructure required
- Increased peak altitude over same rocket launched from ground level

Source: [Astronautix rockoon article](http://www.astronautix.com/r/rockoon.html)

Comment: As someone who used to do science from stratospheric balloons, I would dispute the "Limited ground infrastructure required". The Columbia Scientific Balloon Facility is a serious installation (https://www.csbf.nasa.gov/). To launch a rockoon, you need a facility that can handle a rocket (with all its safety issues) as well as a balloon. Actually launching a balloon is trickier than launching a rocket, as you must manage the effect of even a small breeze. A rockoon has nearly all the disadvantages of both technologies without a significant advantage.

Comment: @JohnDoty I agree w/ you and was careful to include the word "claimed".

Answer (score 7):

The expected advantage of using a balloon to get some "free" lift for a spacecraft, is that you are much higher when you fire your rocket(s), so you should need much less fuel, right?

The issue with this, is that getting into orbit is much more about getting to orbital *speed* rather than getting to orbital *height*.

Having a higher launch point will help a bit by getting into thinner atmosphere, but less than you might expect.

You still need to accelerate your craft to achieve orbit, which the height of your launch has little to do with.

This restriction is reduced for small payloads.

One company, Leo Aerospace LLC, plans to start offering to launch microsatellites using "rockoons".  Michael Hepfer, the head of product development, makes a comparison similar to bulk shipping vs booking an uber.

Individual microsatellites can be launched on their own without waiting to see if there is free space on some other mission.

[Successful “rockoon” launch makes space more accessible to microsatellites](https://engineering.purdue.edu/IE/news/2019/hepfer-leo-rocket-launch)

Comment: Is it possible to add some more to your post that directly answers the question as asked? This is a helpful comment and you have enough reputation to post comments here, but I'm not sure it's really an answer yet. *Thanks!*

Comment: "Escape velocity" is the velocity at which your trajectory becomes gravitationally unbound.  Getting into orbit requires reaching orbital speed, which is significantly lower.

Comment: @Mark  Thanks.  Good point.   I'll modify the answer.